# Global Variable Error

Tags: python

```
   stack = ['','','','','','']
   global first
   global last
   first = 0
   last = 0
   print(stack)
   while True:
       def push():
           if 0 <= last:
               stack[last] = 'D'
               last = last + 1
               if last == 6:
               last = -1
           else:
               print("The stack is full.")
               print(stack)
        def pop():
           stack[last] = ''
           last == stack[last-1]
           print(stack)
           if first == last:
               print("The queue is empty")
       a = input("Push or pop. ")
       if a == 'push':
           push()
       elif a == 'pop':
           pop()
```

I've assigned last as a global variable yet I get this error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'last' referenced before assignment. Considering I've made last a global variable I don't understand why the error is suggesting otherwise, any solutions?

Comment: Don't define functions inside loops. Don't use `global`. Don't preallocate lists.

Comment: I know the use of global variables is bad practice, but why can't it call the global variable from within the loop? @Daniel

Answer (score -1):

The `global` must be inside the `def`. [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)